# How to safely save/retrieve HTML tags to database in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to **safely** save/retrieve HTML tags to a database in my rails app. Currently I save HTML without any validation like below:

```
<h2>Sample title</h2> 
<p>sample description</p>
```

and in the view I use `<%=raw @page.desription %>`. It works as expected. **But I need to know if it is safe or not?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can never be sure it is safe. Always treat all user input as hostile.

However, if by "safe" you mean "devoid of potentially *really* harmful elements like `<script>`s and `<style>`s", then I present to you the [Sanitization Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html). You can print your HTML from the database and only allow a certain whitelist of tags.

`<%=raw sanitize @page.description, tags: %w(h2 p strong em a), attributes: %w(id class href) %>`

The above example will allow all `h2`, `p`, `strong`, `em` and `a` tags, and only the `id`, `class` and `href` attributes on them. Everything else will be removed.

Comment: This sound like a fine solution, It is a description of a product and I need only some of the tags. So if I only allow some of the tags , I am good to go? is there any way to sanitize the data before storing in database?

Comment: You could use this same helper to sanitize input before it goes into the database, I guess, but I personally wouldn't. I would say the best solution would be to store it as the user inputs it and be just be careful to sanitize whenever you output it. (For e.g., maybe in the future you want to allow an element you have previously stripped out)

Comment: Thanks, right, I wait for other answers then I accept the best answer.

Comment: I've recommended some edits to this question because both the question and answer are about how to safely display html tags that have been stored in the database.  It is *not* about how to save those tags to the database in the first place, which is what the original title implied.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe as long as it's from a trusted source, otherwise you won't know what it is they're storing exactly. So if you're the only person storing it, go for it.

Comment: No, I am not the only persion, It is open to public, so how can I be sure now?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605935/database-for-content-ok-to-store-html