# How do i do a custom field in django to "clean" an html field?

Tags: html, django-rest-framework, sanitization

I have a model with description field, this field can be html code,  for security reasons I want to create a custom field to clear this code before saving to db.

I trying to use the lib bleach https://github.com/mozilla/bleach, but i don't know if I'm doing it right

this my customField

```py
class HtmlField(models.TextField):
    description = 'Clean HTML field'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bleach.clean(self.description)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT:

I can save the data the way I want, but I reebo this error not migrate: TypeError: argument cannot be of 'NoneType' type, must be of text type

EDIT2: I solved the previous problem by placing a check if the text is empty:

```py
if not value:
             return ''
```

https://github.com/mozilla/bleach/issues/334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `to_python` function, like:

```
class HtmlField(models.TextField):
    description = 'Clean HTML field'

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        if value is None:
            return None
        return bleach.clean(value)
```

That being said, I'm not convinced that storing HTML code in the database is a security risk. The database does not render the html, it does not run the JavaScript parts, etc. See [the question "*Database for Content - OK to store HTML?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14605935/67579) for more information.

Comment: Thanks i will test this, i think this too, but it's an exigence of project

Comment: This works for me, thanks bro, and a tip for someone who is going to use this: https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html#allowed-tags-tags

Comment: @GustavoNogueira: in case you want to automatically "unclean" it, you need to override the `from_db_value` function`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value

Comment: i dont undestand your last comment

Comment: @GustavoNogueira: can you please edit your question and share the full traceback?

Comment: Yes, one moment please

Comment: @GustavoNogueira: what if you add a `None` check?