# Best way to store rich article content using Firebase & Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, nosql

I'm using Firebase & Vue to create a dynamic site. One section of the site will contain hundreds of article pages in the form:

```
<article>
<!-- order of these elements will not change -->
<h1>Article title</h1>
<div id="date">1/1/2021</div>
<div id="author">Author</div>
<div id="tags">Tag1, Tag2, Tag3</div>

<div id="content">

    <!-- order of elements varies based on needs of article. sample elements below -->
    <h2 class="subtitle>Subtitle 1</h2>
    <p class="text"><span class="smallcaps">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <a href="https://example.com/">link</a>.</p>
    <blockquote>"An embedded tweet"</blockquote><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <h2 class="subtitle>Subtitle 2</h2>
    <p class="text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non:</p>
    <figure><img src="img.jpg"/><figcaption>Caption</figcaption></figure>
    <h2 class="subtitle>Subtitle 3</h2>
    etc...

</div>

</article>
<!-- comments feature below -->
```

In terms of storing the article content, I've come across three options, none of which seem ideal:

1. Store the HTML tags and content within `<div id="content">` inside a field in each article's Firebase document, then use `innerHTML` to inject the contents of that field into `<div id="content">`. Use one `Article.vue` file to pipe in and display each `article` document from the Firebase collection. While this is easy and solves my problem, I'm afraid of XSS attacks, especially since I'll sometimes be using `<script>` to embed content from social media sites like Twitter and YouTube.
2. Create a field in Firebase for each HTML element that I expect within the article (e.g., `subtitle1`, `paragraph1`, `blockquote1`, `subtitle2`, `paragraph2`, etc.). Use one `Article.vue` file to pipe in and display an article's elements. I already planned to do this with the standardized elements, like `title`, `date`, and `author`, but doing so for elements within `<div id="content">` would remove variability in the structure of the articles. Even dealing with external links (i.e., `<a href="https://example.com/">`) within paragraphs would be painful, if not impossible.
3. Make a separate `.vue` file for each article. This allows for full customization of each article, but doesn't scale well with hundreds or thousands of articles.

Is there a better option, or am I stuck with one of these three? I'd prefer not to install CMS software like WordPress in order to keep a consistent feel to my site.

Answer (score 1):

I think answers to this question will largely be opinion based. With that said, just based off of some research and personal experience professionally, I can give some general advice!

### Opinions

1. First, I would say option 2 isn't deal in **any scenario**, unless the articles are going to be exactly the same across the board. You already touched on this, but from a user-interface stand point, every article created on the site would have to be structured the exact same way, and any users creating their own articles *(or blog posts)* would lose that freedom to create their own thing.
2. Secondly, I can't actually think of a way that option 3 would work. How would you render a completely separate `vue` component for each article? How would you determine which article gets what view? If every article got their own entire `vue` component, you'd have thousands *(hundreds of thousands, etc. for a bigger app)* of components inside of your project, and I can't imagine the load that would put on the server you host it on. I doubt most servers could even handle that.

### Questions

1. Instead of having an article be one big HTML block, have you thought of **Markdown**? There's a decent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605935/database-for-content-ok-to-store-html) about how viable Markdown is in your database. Have you ever used a **Github wiki** before? All of those pages are also in markdown, and I absolutely love Github's Wiki features! Here's an example [Github Wiki](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki). There's definitely a ton of JavaScript libraries out there for rendering markdown once it gets back from the server, and it's about the same process as sending HTML to your server: just make sure things are escaped properly. Here's some examples: [MarkedJS](https://github.com/markedjs/marked),  [ShowdownJS](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)
2. Within the realm of Firebase, have you looked into [Flamelink](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/11/flamelink-cms-for-firebase.html)? It looks like it could be a pretty good option for attempting to do a CMS engine inside of Firebase / Firestore.

### Summary

**This is definitely my opinion, and I am in no way an expert or master in my craft.**

If it were me, I probably wouldn't be building a CMS engine inside of `Firebase / Firestore`, only because Firebase was built for fast, ever-changing data, ideally for mobile apps, small web applications, and microservices. The [Firebase Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) has some great history and info on this. Using it as a CMS is probably absolutely possible, but you'd be pushing it to it's limits, and probably getting a huge bill based off of database usage in a production app, compared to a separate API being hosted on Heroku or something similar.

I've been developing professionally for about 4 years now, and in my experience, CMS-level architecture is difficult in any platform, even powerful frameworks like **Rails**, **.NET**, and **Django**.

With all of that being said, **I would probably go for your first option, if nothing else is considered in this answer**. It will allow the user the most freedom, is the most maintainable *(you only have to have one `article_content` component or div, and handle all styling there)*, and as long as your database can handle it, and you escape your HTML properly *(most frameworks do this automatically)*, you should be good to go.

Comment: Otter, this is super helpful. I was unfamiliar with the Markdown and Flamelink options you mentioned. Time to research! Thank you.